# Why is function productAddToCartForm.submit(this) repeating in Firefox?

Tags: magento-1, cart

My add to cart function is working fine in Chrome, but in firefox when you add to cart it adds the product over and over again and never redirects to cart. Do you have any idea what this could be? The only javascript error I receive is this: "ReferenceError: control is not defined" but this error displays when the page is loaded. I do not think it is relevant.

Where add to cart is performed:

```
//Add to cart function
                    $j("button.btn-cart").on("click", function(event){
                        if (loggedInFlag==1){
                            var IDs=[];
                            var vendorID = $j('input[name="customPrice"]:checked').attr('id');
                            $j('#attribute136 option[value="' + vendorID + '"]').prop('selected',true);
                            $j('#attribute136').removeClass('validation-failed').addClass('validation-passed');
                            IDs[0]= vendorID; 


                            updatePrices(IDs, function(){
                                setInterval(function(){productAddToCartForm.submit(this)},2500);
                            });
                        }
                        else{
                            alert('You must be registered and logged in to add to cart.');
                        }
                    });
```

I checked to make sure updatePrices was not repeating for some reason. I put a console.log("hey im here") within it, but no.. it was not repeating.

This is what's going on with the network:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your `setInterval` function. See function description [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

> The setInterval() method calls a function or evaluates an expression
>   at specified intervals (in milliseconds).
>
> The setInterval() method **will continue calling the function until
>   clearInterval()** is called, or the window is closed.
>
> The ID value returned by setInterval() is used as the parameter for
>   the clearInterval() method.

I think you are looking for `setTimeout()` instead of `setInterval()`